# apt-get failure in chroot environment

Tags: yocto, apt, chroot

My host system is a ubuntu:18.04 docker container. There I have built a root filesystem for x86_64 architecture using the yocto project. The location of the root-fs is defined by ${IMAGE_ROOTFS} variable. I chroot in the system and try to install dos2unix package. My code looks like this:

```
    mount --bind /proc ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/proc 
    mount --bind /dev ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/dev 

    # copy host files to make network function in chroot
    sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/resolv.conf

    # configure apt
    sudo mkdir -p ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/log/apt

    # set time
    sudo cp ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/localtime

    #######################
    #### Entering Chroot 
    #######################

    # chroot into the target system 
    sudo chroot ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/bin/bash

    # install packages
    apt-get install -y dos2unix
```

But, I get the following error:

```
bash-4.4# apt-get install dos2unix
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dos2unix is already the newest version (7.3.4-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
E: Can not write log (Is /dev/pts mounted?) - posix_openpt (2: No such file or directory)
Setting up sysvinit-inittab (2.88dsf-r10) ...
/bin/sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
dpkg: error processing package sysvinit-inittab (--configure):
 installed sysvinit-inittab package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sysvinit-inittab
E: Directory '/var/log/apt/' missing
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It seems like the root-fs is not fully configured to run apt. What additional packages do I need to add to yocto?

UPDATE-1:
A little bit of context: I was not sure of how to install deb packages from apt sources in yocto during image build-time. So I set about creating a post-process script for the rootfilesystem, to execute apt and install the packages. There I am using apt to install packages from variety of apt sources including a custom apt source.

Comment: You have made ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/log/apt but have you made ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/var/log/apt? Also, in my experience, timezones should be symbolic links and not copied, but I've never used Yocto before.

Comment: @Aurelius My bad. And what about sysvinit-inittab error. Is it related to /var/log/apt?

Comment: It's hard to say, because it just says the post-installation script returned an error. Once you've created the proper apt log directory, you can take a look at a more detailed log, I believe. It's possible that the error the post-installation script is having is that it's also unable to write to the apt log directory.

Comment: Maybe tell us a bit more about your use case. Because if its only about dos2unix, no need to do that dance: just add it through Yocto itself, a recipe is provided even in core: http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-support/dos2unix/dos2unix_7.4.0.bbhttp://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-support/dos2unix/dos2unix_7.4.0.bb Having said that, here is extensive information aout running package managers inside Yocto-based builds: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/package-manager-white-paper.pdf

Comment: @LetoThe2nd It is not just for dos2unix. I was not sure of how to install deb packages from apt sources in yocto. So I set about creating a post-process script for  the rootfilesystem, to execute apt and install the packages. There I am using apt to install packages from variety of apt sources including a custom apt source.

Comment: @LetoThe2nd And the link you provided for package-management is for the runtime. I am looking for a build-time solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Given the additional explanation, the Yocto-style solution is as follows:

You would write a recipe for each item that you want to install into the image. If it is a package of some form that is bundled as a `.deb`, then the standard approach is called "packaging externally produced binaries" and described [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#packaging-externally-produced-binaries). Then you create an image recipe that pulls in all those things.

As you have specifically asked for a build-type solution, this is the way to go. The start-in-docker approach could be considered "build time" from your point of view, as the Dockerfile is executed ahead of time. But from the POV of the image, it is runtime as you chroot into it and execute things on it.